# Would this question be more suitable for Math Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, migration, mathoverflow

I asked the following question, but I didn't get any answer, even after adding a bounty:

[Finite-sample confidence interval for the sample mean of N iid Beta-Binomial random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416972/finite-sample-confidence-interval-for-the-sample-mean-of-n-iid-beta-binomial-ran)

Do you think I would have more luck on Math Overflow, or should I just give up?

Comment: Have you considered https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @postmortes  Heh, I originally posted it there, but it got even less attention than it got here...

Comment: Your question seems very hard, so it is plausible it is research level, meaning it is OK to post to MO.

Comment: The only way to know, decisively, is if you post it on MO to see what happens.  We are not fortune tellers wrt other sites on SE. Math.meta.se is for questions about math.se; not about every SE site on this network.